# Top 10-15 rails view helpers I should learn first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am learning rails 3, and want to know which view helpers I should master first?

i.e. which ones are used the most often?

```
1. form_for
2. ??
..
..
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think these are generally considered quite important and they should give you a great start to understanding code and creating forms and pages of your own.

1. form_for
2. link_to
3. image_tag
4. stylesheet_link_tag
5. javascript_include_tag
6. content_for
7. label_tag
8. text_field_tag
9. submit_tag
10. select_tag
11. options_for_select
12. check_box_tag
13. radio_button_tag
14. form_tag
15. collection_select

Some other useful ones as well:

1. auto_link
2. pluralize
3. simple_format

I would also work on understanding the difference between simply calling select_tag and calling f.select, where f is a form_for variable. These are generally the two different ways in which you create forms with helpers in Rails.

I would also make sure you understand the html_safe, raw and h functions for strings and displaying text on your page.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already, read through the tutorial here:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html